# Correct way to inject service into its own module and the one that imports it

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a service (`LogoutService`) in that can be injected only in its module  (AuthModule) and the module that imports it.  For `LogoutService` when used `providedIn: AuthModule` which is throwing an Error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'AuthModule' before initialization`. Instead if `providedIn: 'root'` there are no any errors but the service is available throughout the application. Why is this throwing the error?

---

```
  @NgModule({
        declarations:[LoginComponent, LogoutComponent, HomeComponent],
        exports:[LoginComponent,LogoutComponent, HomeComponent]
    })
    export class AuthModule {
    
    }
```

---

```
import { AuthModule } from './auth.module'
@Injectable({
    providedIn: AuthModule
}  
)
export class LogoutService{
    constructor(){

    }
    isLogout(){
        console.log("Is logout successful");
    }
}
```

---

```
 @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        DemoDynamicComponent,
        TestComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        AuthModule     //Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'AuthModule' before initialization
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Option `providedIn?: Type<any>` is [deprecated](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable). Anyway this option was not usable because of problems with component lifecycle and possible circular references.

You can provide service trough module injector by adding it to the NgModule providers array:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [LogoutService]
}) export class AuthModule {}
```